# print progress counter of python in DOS

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

[image]

```
test_count = 0

while test_count <= 100:
    print test_count
    test_count +=1
```

Currently this counter is printing on next line but I am looking for way to overwrite it on "0".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\r` carriage-return character with `sys.stdout.flush`.

```
import sys
import time  # for invoking time.sleep(n_seconds) inside loop

counter = 0
while counter <= 100:
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
    sys.stdout.write("\rTesting (%ss elapsed)" % counter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r` and add a `,` at the end of your print statement to not automatically write a newline as in the code below.

Also, see the [python-progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/) library for some nice text implementations of progress bars.

```
import time # Added to demonstrate effect

test_count = 0

while test_count <= 100:
    print "\r%3d" % test_count,
    time.sleep(0.1)
    test_count +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the following statement(s):
First import 'os' module at beginning of the file:

```
import os
```

Then add this at the end of your loop:

```
os.system('cls')
```

Hope, that helped you :)